# How to efficiently make a query based on the value of a subchild key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my DB:

```
MessagesInvolvingUserID:
  - [UserID01]:
    - [MessageID01]: [TimeStamp01]
    - [MessageID02]: [TimeStamp02]
    ...
  - [UserID02]:
    - [MessageID03]: [TimeStamp03]
    - [MessageID04]: [TimeStamp04]
    ...
```

I'm wondering how to efficiently construct a Dictionary representing the latest messageID (based on timestamp value) for each UserID ?

I think a "brute force" approach would work:

1. observe MessagesInvolvingUserID for value
2. loop over every snapshot the filter the latest message ID
3. construct the Dictionary

But that seems awfully inefficient since that involves downloading and doing the work client side.  Any suggestion for a more elegant approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a list that shows the latest timestamp for each user, you should store a list that shows the latest timestamp for each user in your database.

```
LatestTimstampForUserID:
  - [UserID01]: [TimeStamp02]
  - [UserID02]: [TimeStamp04]
    ...
```

Now you can very efficiently read this data from the database and show the list.

The cost is that you'll need to update multiple locations in the database when a new message is posted for a user. This is very common when using NoSQL databases, such as the Firebase Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1):

Why don’t you make a Timestamp key under each message with timestamp value and then query messages sorting them by their timestamps? What language are you using to query items from the database? Have you tried something like:

```
ref.child(“MessagesInvolvingUserID”).child(userID).child("MessageID01").queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in ...
```